# Unable to initiate a variable using @Value annotation, spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My process class:

```
@Configurable("checkLicense")
public class CheckLicense {
String licensePath ;

@Value("${licenseKeyNotFound}")
String licenseKeyNotFound;

    public boolean checkIn(String licensepath) {
        System.out.println("hello "+licenseKeyNotFound);
        licensePath = licensepath;
        return checkIn();
    }

}
```

My ApplicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <bean class="com.smart.applicationlicense.CheckLicense"
        scope="prototype">
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Here is my properties file.

```
licenseKeyNotFound = License File Corrupted
```

Here is my servlet xml.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="conf/LicenseSettings.properties"
    order="2" ignore-unresolvable="true" />
```

Eventhough I have used the `@Configurable` annotation along with the attributes `Autowire.BY_NAME, Autowire.BY_TYPE`, I am unable to initiate the variable of `licenseKeyNotFound` from the property file.
I was able to initiate the variable from a controller but not from this class which is  declared `@Configurable`.

Can anyone please let me know what I am missing or what's wrong with my code?
Please let me know if there is something required from my code.

Comment: Isn't the `id` mandatory in a *bean* declaration?

Comment: @ring0 Referred to [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable) and found that it is not mandatory.

Comment: any other answers or suggestions?

Comment: `licenseKeyNotFound` is to be found from a properties file - I don't see any declaration of a prop file in your snippet. Maybe the answer is a mix between Festus answer (replace a *String* with a *method*) and Kent answer (provide a properties file).

Comment: @ring0 I have added snippets to the question. Please let me know if this is what your comment is about.

Comment: Doesn't ignore-unresolvable ignore any errors if it can't read the properties file?  Are you sure the properties file is being loaded?

Comment: @CodeChimp Yes properties file is being loaded from the `controller` but not from this class with `@Configurable`.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

in your spring xml:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:your.properties" />
<context:load-time-weaver />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Configurable
public class CheckLicense {
   String licensePath;
   String licenseKeyNotFound;

   @Value("${licenseKeyNotFound}")   
   public void setLicenseKeyNotFound(String licenseKeyNotFound) {
      this.licenseKeyNotFound = licenseKeyNotFound;
   }

   public boolean checkIn(String licensepath) {
      System.out.println("hello " + licenseKeyNotFound);
      licensePath = licensepath;
      return checkIn();
   }
}
```

in your properties file

```
licenseKeyNotFound=${value}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for a quick answer. Should I not use the @Configurable annotation?

Comment: Used your solution with and without the @Configurable but in vain.

Comment: which class and package does this @Property annotation come from?

Comment: Still not working, is there something else you would want me to post? I mean, in the question, from my code.